# geolib function is not returning the value

Tags: react-native

i am calling the function to get distance of lat long, but it is returning undefined.

```
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {

 const distance = this.getDistance(latitude, longitude)
        console.log('distance', distance)
}
```

here is my function.

```
getDistance(latitude, longitude) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function (position) {
            var distance = geolib.getDistance(position.coords, {
                latitude: parseInt(latitude),
                longitude: parseInt(longitude),
            })
            console.log('distance:', distance) //getting right value 54209m
            return distance;

        },
        function () {
            alert('Position could not be determined.')
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }

    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `getCurrentPosition` in a promise so that you can resolve the distance, trying to return something like you are doing won't work.

What this means is that `getDistance` will now return a promise. That promise will `resolve` when it has a distance, and it will `reject` when you get an error.

```
getDistance = async (latitude, longitude) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      var distance = geolib.getDistance(position.coords, {
        latitude: parseInt(latitude),
        longitude: parseInt(longitude),
    })
    console.log('distance:', distance); //getting right value 54209m
    resolve(distance);
    }, err => {
      reject(err);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }
    );
  })
}
```

Then you should update your `onCollectionUpdate` function to handle the promise that your `getDistance` function will return. Notice that you have to wrap it inside a `try/catch` as `await` functions can throw.

```
onCollectionUpdate = async (querySnapshot) => {
  try  {
    const distance = await this.getDistance(latitude, longitude);
    console.log('distance', distance);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Position could not be determined.') // <- put the alert here as this is where the error will be caught
  }       
}
```